# Move 2 images to the page corner parallel

Tags: html, css, animation

**I have 2 images like that:**

```
<div id="logos_Body">
  <div id="logo1_Body">
    <img src='image1.png' id="logo1" width="334.2" height="369.2">
  </div>
  <div id="logo2_Body">
    <img src="image2.png" id="logo2" width="180" height="70">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#logos_Body{
animation:LogosMove 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes LogoMove {
  100% { top:-80px; left:-150px; width:170px; height:140px;}  
}

#logo1{
animation:Logo1Move 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Logo1Move {
 100% {  width:90px; height: 110px;}  
 }

#logo2{
animation:logo2Move 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes logo2Move {
  100% { width:75px; height: 30px;}  
}
```

These images must initially appear in the middle of the page with showed  width and height. I want to move them to the right corner of the page, and reduce their width and height too.
I used `animation` property as shown above, the problem is the first image is go right with no problems ( moving & resizing ) but the second image reduces right but not move to the corner rightly .

I think that the problem is `image1` height is related, but i am not sure, i don't know how to fix this,, thanks.

1- initial appearance.
2- I need them like that.
3- what the above code gives me.
[image]